# Longitudinal EMAG wave?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, waves, waveguide

I'm reading about optical waveguide analysis, and often come across the terms "transverse electric mode" vs. "transverse magnetic mode". As I unerstand, it means that the electric/magnetic field has only transversal component.

But how could it have longitudinal component? Aren't the electric and magnetic fields always perpendicular to the direction of propagation?

Comment: *"Aren't the electric and magnetic fields always perpendicular to the direction of propagation?"* In free space, yes. However, waveguides can support waves with longitudinal field components. I seem to recall that most texts do an example of one of those, but it has been a long time...

Comment: Electrostatic waves have $\mathbf{k} \ \times \ \mathbf{E}$ = 0, but then again, I think they can only exist in a medium, not a vacuum.  Hmm...

Comment: @dmckee not even in free space.  If you form a finite beam it will have a small longitudinal component.  It's true that plane waves in free space have no longitudinal component but plane waves do not exist in nature.